# how to fix django-db-mailer SMS API language argument changing the language of the application

Tags: python, django

when we are applying language='ar' kwargs to the send_db_sms() API it will change the Language of the entire web application.

```
from dbmail import send_db_sms
send_db_sms(
    # slug which defined on db template
    slug='welcome',

    # recipient can be list, or str separated with comma or simple 
    # string    
    recipient='+79031234567',

    # All *args params will be accessible on template context
    {
        'username': request.user.username,
        'full_name': request.user.get_full_name(),
        'signup_date': request.user.date_joined
    },

    # Optional kwargs:

    language='ar',
    )
```

by giving language='ar',kwargs to the send_db_sms() function, it should not change the language of the entire web application.

Please help,

Comment: language='ar', is used to send a message in a specified language format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
send_db_sms(
      sms_template,
      mobile_number,
      {},
      language='DE'
   )
translation.activate(self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

there is some bug in

> django-dbmailer

library so after using send_db_sms with language option one should use below code to continue in the same language otherwise it will change the language of the whole site

> translation.activate(self.request.LANGUAGE_CODE)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, it should not happen.

It may possible that you have defined the language variable outside the function too and it is overriding all the variables. Please check that you haven't used it anywhere else.

Apart from that, you can have a default language for your application outside of this function so, outside this function your app will consider that default language.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not defined any language variable outside the function.

default language is already set in settings.py